# How to trigger a form inside a component from VueX store

Tags: forms, vue.js, store, vuex

I'm calling an action in the store to send data to an API.
This call is triggered from a button in FormComponent from @click :

```
<button type="button" @click="$store.dispatch('saveStoreDatas')">Click me</button>
```

How can I submit the parent form of button (omitted code) ? I cannot use a ref because it's inside a component.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to dispatch an action **and** submit the form? Normally you can just have form data in the store and send it in the action.

If you really need to submit the form, emit an event in the child component and listen for the event in the parent component.

Child component will goes like this.

```
<!-- child component template -->
<button type="button" @click="handleClick">Click me</button>

// child component script
methods: {
    handleClick () {
        this.$store.dispatch('saveStoreDatas')
        this.$emit('clickSubmit')
    }
}
```

And this is its parent.

```
<!-- parent template -->
<form ref="form">
    <child-component @clickSubmit="submitForm">
</form>

// parent component script
methods: {
    submitForm () {
        this.$refs.form.submit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, this is the way ! :)

Comment: I don't get it. What's the role and magic of unused method `submitForm()`?

Comment: `submitForm` is triggered on `clickSubmit` event of the child component. `clickSubmit` is emitted in `handleClick` method, which will be invoked on clicking the `button`. 
`submitForm` gets the form element in the parent component (`this.$refs.form`) 
 and submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate function for the click handler:

```
<button type="button" @click.prevent="submitToStore">Click me</button>
...
...
methods () {
  submitToStore () {
    // refs can be used here - get your form data and send it to the store
    let formData = this.$refs.myForm.data()
    this.$store.dispatch('saveStoreDatas', formData)
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just use `;`

attribute `@click="$store.dispatch('saveStoreDatas');$emit('clickSubmit')"`

```
<button type="button" @click="$store.dispatch('saveStoreDatas');$emit('clickSubmit')">Click me</button>
```